# Can't get XML node info to trace out :(

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

this should be a very simple trace out... but I have no idea why it's not working.

**My XML**
 old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for each(var vidXml:XML in xmlData.col[0].vid.*) {
    trace("loop # = "+vidXml);
    aNewTextArray.push(vidXml);
}
```

^ Try this

Comment: Ah sweet this works :) thx man
So correct trace is:
trace("Where is my text? = "+xmlData.col[0].vid.*);

Didn't think of col as an Array :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
trace("Where is my text? = "+xmlData.col.(@id1 == 'Photography').vid.*);
```

Comment: Just tried that, but got this error: Error #1065: Variable @id1 is not defined. Should @id1 here be some sort of XML var?